# Wordpress fetch blog posts excluding a category ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show the latest blog posts on my wordpress website. I am working with this code, which shows the latest 3 blog posts with any category.

```
<?php 
                
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3');     
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); 

?>



<!-- main content here -->  
<div class="blog-post"> 
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 20, ' ...' ); ?>
</div> 
        
                
<?php 

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();    
                        
?>
```

Now I'd like to exclude a post category from this script (all posts with the category ID 17 should be excluded. I've tried the following scripts, but either way it won't show any posts (all the code stays the same, except the first few lines I changed and tried)

This one did not show anything

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3', 'cat=-17');
```

Tried with array:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($argsQuery); 

$argsQuery = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'cat' => '-17',
);
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Will give me the following error: ```syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'```

Comment: From the manual: Display all posts except those from a category by prefixing its id with a ‘-‘ (minus) sign. `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '-12,-34,-56' ) );` You can [find the manual here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I add the following code, it does indeed hide the posts with the specific category, but it shows all posts and I'd like to only show 3, what did I do wrong here? ```$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '-17', 'posts_per_page=3' ) );```

Comment: The correct is: `$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '-17', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '-17', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );
```